# Force FlowLayoutPanel to re-layout controls.

Tags: c#, forms, user-interface

I have a FlowLayoutPanel in a SplitContainer. When the user resizes the form (and the SplitContainer) I want to change the FlowLayoutPanel's `WrapContents` attribute to false, and allow the Controls in the panel to stretch out the the left and right instead of a strait up and down list.

Though, when I change the `WrapContents` attribute the FlowLayoutPanel does not re-layout the Controls, it actually seemingly does nothing. (I take it that the attribute is only taken into account when something is newly added?)

Is there a way to force the FlowLayoutPanel to re-lay out all of the controls it owns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by changing the `.FlowDirection` of the `FlowLayoutPanel` like so,

```
private void fillFlowCheck_CheckedChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lastFlowDirection == FlowDirection.TopDown)
        viewPanel.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
    else if (lastFlowDirection == FlowDirection.LeftToRight)
        viewPanel.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;
    lastFlowDirection = viewPanel.FlowDirection;
}
```

Though this fix wasn't made for the original problem, it does fix the original problem too.